# How to store image name/value on submit in mysql from a form (i.e same as radio button)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I'm making a form and I want user to enter the name and email and choose an image from all the given images and submit so the name, email and chooses image name will be stored in database but I'm only able to store the name and email in the database not the image name/value.

I have tried to make it input radio or use option.

My PHP File

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );


    /* change this to include YOUR db connection or edit as appropriate */
    $dbhost =   '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   ''; 
    $dbname =   'test';
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );





    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){   

        if( empty( $errors ) ){

            $sql='insert into `registration`
                ( `name`,`email`,`amount` )
                values
                ( ?,?,? )';

            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) {
                /* Investigate errors and make corrections to db table &/or sql statement */
                exit( sprintf( 'Bad Foo! - %s', $db->error )  );
            }
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'sss',
                $name,
                $email,
                $amount
            );        

        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />

    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                if( !empty( $status ) ){

                    $message = $status ? 'success: record added' : 'failure: record was not added';
                    $amount  = $status ? 'green' : 'red';

                    printf('<span style="color:%s">%s</span>', $amount, $message );
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class='row' style='margin-top: 50px;'>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Enter name' required />
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' required />
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <option>
                    <div class="card">
                      <img src="img/dj/lemon.jpg" alt="DJ Lemon" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="container">
                        <h4>DJ Lemon</h4> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </option>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <option>
                    <div class="card">
                      <img src="img/dj/rink.jpg" alt="DJ Rink" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="container">
                        <h4>DJ Rink</h4> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </option>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <option>
                      <div class="card">
                          <img src="img/dj/akbar.jpg" alt="DJ Akbar Sami" style="width:100%">
                      <div class="container">
                        <h4>DJ Akbar Sami</h4> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </option>
                </div>
            </div>


            </div>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <input type='submit' />
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                /* were there any errors? display them perhaps... */
                if( !empty( $errors ) ) printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $errors, true ) );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

MySQL File

```
CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `registration`
--
ALTER TABLE `registration`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

I expect the name, email and only one selected image name should store in the mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 arguments on bind

```
$stmt->bind_param(
                'sss',
                $name,
                $email,
                $amount
            );
```

And you need to name the options

Comment: It doesn't help, I have tried it. And neither it let me choose.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a concept. In the php you'll get `$_POST['img']` with the name of the clicked image.

The Javascript uses an 'click' event handler for each image. If clicked on an image then the src is read from that image and put in the hidden input field in the form.

```
<style>
.card img {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
.card img:hover, .card img:active {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
</style>

<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="img" id="img" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <div class="card">
    <img src="img-01.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="img-02.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="img-03.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
var i, images = document.querySelectorAll('.card img');
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var src = this.getAttribute("src");
    document.querySelector('#img').setAttribute("value", src);
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't work and it doesn't let me select the image. So because of that not I didn't get to store the data in database.

Comment: Hi Mohammad. Please hit F12 in Chrome and give a look on tab Elements. After clicking an image, the image filename is inserted in the form. In the php you'll get the filename with `$img = $_POST['img'];` Let me know if having problems at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements for storing an image name doesn't quite match the table schema you have designed - surely you would want a field called `img`? The `prepared statement` that you create does not get executed. You asked how to select one of the images and use it's source as the input to the hidden field yet you had no javascript that even attempted that task - the js below is very simple and does simply add the images src attribute as the value to the form element `img`

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );


    $dbhost =   '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'test';
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


    $errors=array();


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* 
            The form has 3 input elements - filter them 
            as a precaution and extract as variables
        */
        $args=array(
            'name'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'email'         =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'img'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        extract( $_POST );

        $img=basename( $img );


        if( empty( $errors ) and isset( $name, $email, $img ) ){

            /* 
                WHERE is the field for the image name?? 
                Presumably you are using `amount` for that purpose ???? 
            */
            $sql='insert into `registration`
                ( `name`,`email`,`amount` )
                values
                ( ?,?,? )';

            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ) {
                exit( sprintf( 'Bad Foo! - %s', $db->error )  );
            }
            $stmt->bind_param(
                'sss',
                $name,
                $email,
                $img
            );

            $status=$stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>select image within form</title>
        <style>
            .card img {
                cursor: pointer;
                border: 2px solid grey;
            }
            .card img:hover, .card img:active {
                border: 2px solid orange;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

                /* The hidden input element will receive the image source as it's value */
                const _input=document.querySelector('input[ name="img" ]');

                /* Find ALL images within the form that match the following pattern & assign event listener */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('div.card > img') ).forEach( img=>{
                    img.addEventListener('click',function(e){

                        /* Set the value */
                        _input.value=this.src;

                        /* FYI */
                        console.info( '"%s" has been assigned as the value for "%s"',this.src, _input.name );
                    })
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <?php

                if( empty( $errors ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    printf('<h2>%s</h2>', $status ? 'Record added' : 'Fooey - record insert failed' );
                }

            ?>
            <input type='hidden' name='img' value='' required />
            <input type='text' name='name' value='' required />
            <input type='text' name='email' value='' required />

            <div class='card'>
                <img src='img-01.jpg' alt='' />
            </div>

            <div class='card'>
                <img src='img-02.jpg' alt='' />
            </div>

            <div class='card'>
                <img src='img-03.jpg' alt='' />
            </div>

            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```